# Streaming the Microphone output via HTTP POST using chunked transfer

Tags: javascript, android, python, http, audio

We are trying to build an app to broadcast live audio to multiple subscribers. The server(written in go) accepts pcm data through chunks and a client using pyaudio is able to tap into the microphone and send this data using the below code. We have tested this and it works. The audio plays from any browser with the subscriber URL.

```
import pyaudio
import requests
import time


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# frames per buffer ?
CHUNK = 1024
# 16 bits per sample ?
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
# 44.1k sampling rate ?
RATE = 44100
# number of channels
CHANNELS = 1

STREAM = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)
print "initialized stream"


def get_chunks(stream):
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = stream.read(CHUNK,exception_on_overflow=False)
            yield chunk
        except IOError as ioe:
            print "error %s" % ioe

url = "https://<server-host>/stream/publish/<uuid>/"

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'Content-Type': "audio/x-wav;codec=pcm"})
resp = s.post(url, data=get_chunks(STREAM))
```

But we need a browser, iOS and Android client to do the same thing as the above client does. We are able to fetch the audio from the mic using the getUserMedia API on the browser but are unable to send this audio to the server like the python code above does. Can someone throw some light in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is about a year old now so I am sure you've moved on but I think that the approach to use from the browser is to stream the data over a WebSocket rather than over HTTP.